# Accessing the Index of an array in LISP

Tags: arrays, lisp

I am working on LISP programming , where I have to find the MAX from an array.
I have written some initial code but stuck there. I have seen many online tutorials but there was not enough help which I could understand.

Here is my code. Up till Now I have created an array of size 5 .I got this method from an online tutorial .

```
(make-array 5)
#(nil nil nil nil nil)
```

Now what I want is to set values on these array indexes and then how I can access those indexes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store it some place where you can use it. Eg.

```lisp
(let ((my-array (make-array 11 :initial-element 7)))
   (aref my-array 5)         ;; ==> 7
   (setf (aref my-array 3) 2);; ==> 2
   my-array)                 ;; ==> #(7 7 7 2 7 ...)
```

It can be lexical as in my example, but you can make it as package variable as well (global).

Comment: I have tried here
http://www.compileonline.com/execute_lisp_online.php

The code is not working.

Comment: @farhangdon I had a missing hyphen on 3. line. You need to wrap the expressions you want to see with `print`, like `(print (aref my-array 5))` if you want output in your online evaluator.